# Mailer helpers in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper

I'm trying to get the following code:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def make_email(full_name, email_name)
    @email = full_name + " <" + email_name + "@" + DOMAIN + ">"
  end
end
```

to be seen inside my Mailer (ActionMailer class). I understand from here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers
that this should work, however the mailer can't actually see the function, and I get an undefined error.

What am I doing wrong/what could I do better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says `ActionMailer` inherits from `AbstractController`. In a regular controller (e.g. standard example `PostsController`) you can't access methods from `PostsHelper` or `ApplicationHelper` without explicitly including the helper in your controller.  E.g. By default you cannot use `link_to` inside a controller.

So, if you want to use this method inside your `Mailer` class, you need to `include ApplicationHelper`.